# mysql error (Column count doesn't match value count at row 1)

Tags: php, mysql

I have SQL syntax:

```
$input = mysql_query("INSERT INTO member (id_member, fullname, username, password, email, phone, ktp, address) VALUES ('$idm', '$fullname','$username', '$password', '$email', '$phone', '$ktp', '$address')") or die ("Error..".mysql_error());
```

When I'm running this code i got an error like this (Column doesn't match value count at row 1).

Comment: `$address` perhaps having single quote in the string, so better start using prepared statement.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the value of all 8 variables?

Comment: Can you echo out the statement and port the result. I t looks like you have a ',' in your variables.

Comment: Stop using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*`or PDO with prepared statement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

single quotation mark `''` does not parse the variable rather than send whatever inside as it is, so basically you insert a string valued `$idm` itself instead of its value. So what you need is to make the variable out of the string.

```
$input = mysql_query("INSERT INTO member (id_member, fullname, username, password, email, phone, ktp, address) VALUES ('".$idm."', '".$fullname."','".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email".', '".$phone."', '".$ktp."', '".$address."')") or die ("Error..".mysql_error());
```

Comment: Do you mind adding a common warning about [SQL injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)?